SQLAlchemy connection works but the Flask app crash
I'm writing a simple website that uses postgresql, sqlalchemy, and flask.
I have a server on which my DB is installed, and when I connect to it via this code: the connection is successful.
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from Back.App.helpers import singleton
from Back.App.orms import Base
from sqlalchemy.sql import and_  
from datetime import date
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()

# wrapper is the same as:
# DbManager = singleton(DbManager)

# every db manager instance is the same to avoid multiple sessions, db connections and ssh tunnels
@singleton
class DbManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tunnel = None
        self.engine = None
        self.SessionFactory = None
        self.session = None
        self.start_tunnel()

    def start_tunnel(self):
        """Start the SSH tunnel."""
        self.tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(
            (os.getenv('SSH_HOST'), int(os.getenv('SSH_PORT'))),
            ssh_username=os.getenv('SSH_USERNAME'),
            ssh_password=os.getenv('SSH_PASSWORD'),
            remote_bind_address=(os.getenv('DB_HOST'), int(os.getenv('DB_PORT'))),
            local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 6543)
        )
        self.tunnel.start()
        print(f"SSH tunnel established on local port {self.tunnel.local_bind_port}")

        # Set up the SQLAlchemy engine and session
        db_url = (f"postgresql://{os.getenv('DB_USER')}:{os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD')}@127.0.0.1:"
                  f"{self.tunnel.local_bind_port}/{os.getenv('DB_NAME')}")
        self.engine = create_engine(db_url, pool_pre_ping=True)
        Base.metadata.bind = self.engine
        self.SessionFactory = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = self.SessionFactory()

    def close(self):
        """Close the SSH tunnel and the SQLAlchemy session."""
        if self.session:
            self.session.close()
        if self.tunnel:
            self.tunnel.stop()
            print("SSH tunnel closed.")

    def get_objects(self, db_object, *filters):
        """
        Fetch objects based on filters.
        Returns a tuple: (success, data_or_message).
        """
        try:
            query = self.session.query(db_object)
            if filters:
                query = query.filter(and_(*filters))
            objects = query.all()

            if not objects:
                return False, "No rows found in the database."

            return True, objects
        except Exception as e:
            return False, f"Error fetching objects: {str(e)}"


from Back.App.orms import Student, Volunteer, AreaManager, Organization
from datetime import date
from db_connection import DbManager

db_manager = DbManager()

success, students = db_manager.get_objects(Student)
"students:"
for student in students:
    print(f"ID: {student.student_id}, Name: {student.first_name} {student.last_name}, City: {student.city}")

I have an app.py file that currently has a basic login connection to the site, and when I try to open the first html page, I get an error that doesn't allow me to see the screen.
the app.py file:
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import login_user, LoginManager, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from Back.App.orms import User, Student, Volunteer, AreaManager
from db_connection import DbManager
import os

# Initialize Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)

# Configure app settings
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = (
    f"postgresql://{os.getenv('DB_USER')}:{os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD')}@"
    f"127.0.0.1:6543/{os.getenv('DB_NAME')}")

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisisasecretkey'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

# Initialize database
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Set up Flask-Login
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    """Load user by ID."""
    return db.session.get(User, user_id)
    # return db.session.query(User).get(user_id)



# Flask-WTF Forms
class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(
        validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)],
        render_kw={"placeholder": "id"}
    )
    password = PasswordField(
        validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=20)],
        render_kw={"placeholder": "Password"}
    )
    submit = SubmitField('Register')


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(
        validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)],
        render_kw={"placeholder": "id"}
    )
    password = PasswordField(
        validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=20)],
        render_kw={"placeholder": "Password"}
    )
    submit = SubmitField('Login')


# Flask routes
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        db_manager = DbManager()

        # Fetch the user
        success, user_data = db_manager.get_objects(User, User.user_id == form.username.data)

        # Check if the user exists
        if not success:
            return jsonify({"error": "Database error occurred while fetching user."}), 500
        if not user_data:
            return jsonify({"error": "Invalid username or password."}), 400

        # Get the user object and verify the password
        user = user_data[0]
        if not bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.user_password, form.password.data):
            return jsonify({"error": "Invalid username or password."}), 400

        # Log in the user
        login_user(user)

        # Redirect based on user_type
        if user.user_type == "student":
            return redirect(url_for('student_home')), 200
        elif user.user_type == "volunteer":
            return redirect(url_for('volunteer_home')), 200
        elif user.user_type == "area_manager":
            return redirect(url_for('area_manager_home')), 200
        else:
            return jsonify({"error": "Invalid user type."}), 400

    # Render the login form for GET requests or invalid submissions
    return render_template('login.html', form=form), 200



@app.route('/student/home')
@login_required
def student_home():
    return render_template('student_home.html')


@app.route('/volunteer/home')
@login_required
def volunteer_home():
    return render_template('volunteer_home.html')


@app.route('/manager/home')
@login_required
def manager_home():
    return render_template('area_manager_home.html')


@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))


@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')

        db_manager = DbManager()

        # Check if the username already exists
        existing_username, user_list = db_manager.get_objects(User, User.user_id == form.username.data)
        if existing_username:
            return jsonify({"error": "id already exists. Please choose a different one."}), 400

        # Check if the password hash already exists
        existing_passwords, password_list = db_manager.get_objects(User, User.user_password == hashed_password)
        print("user: ", User.user_password, "form: ", hashed_password)
        print(existing_passwords)
        if existing_passwords:
            return jsonify({"error": "Password already exists. Please choose a different one."}), 400

        # Determine user type
        user_id = form.username.data
        user_type = None
        try:
            if db_manager.get_objects(Student, Student.student_id == user_id):
                user_type = "student"
            elif db_manager.get_objects(Volunteer, Volunteer.volunteer_id == user_id):
                user_type = "volunteer"
            elif db_manager.get_objects(AreaManager, AreaManager.area_managers_id == user_id):
                user_type = "area_manager"
            else:
                return jsonify({"error": "User ID not found in any table."}), 400
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({"error": f"An error occurred while verifying user ID: {str(e)}"}), 500

        # Create the new user object
        new_user = User(user_id=form.username.data, user_password=hashed_password, user_type=user_type)
        success, message = db_manager.insert_object(new_user)

        if success:
            # return jsonify({"message": "User registered successfully."}), 201
            return redirect(url_for('login')), 201
        else:
            return jsonify({"error": message}), 500

    # return jsonify({"error": "Invalid form submission."}), 400
    return render_template('register.html', form=form), 400


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


this is thy error: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 6543 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
and it fails on this line:
@app.route('/student/home')
@login_required
def student_home():
    return render_template('student_home.html') #here it fails

The strange thing is that two days ago this connection via flask worked, and I didn't change anything in the app.py file.
Does anyone have an idea what could be causing the problem?
i tried putting port 5432 and changing the host in the  ['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] in app.py, and i tried changing the sqlalchemy versions, with no success.
